# HTML5 Audio Stream Latency, Force Play?

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio, audio-streaming

**How do you make the HTML5 audio element start playing a low bit-rate audio stream immediately?**

For a live example of the problem, [visit this webpage](http://webtests.online/LiveHTML5Audio.php).

---

### Problem

I am streaming low-bit rate ogg/opus to a HTML5 audio element. It works well except for one problem.

On the two browsers I've tested (Chrome and Firefox), the browsers buffer until 32 kB of data is received. This can be anywhere from 20-40 seconds into the audio file.

When ~32 kB is hit, the browser fires the `loadeddata` event along with a `readyState` of `3`, followed immediately by the `canplay` event.

**Example code:**

```
<audio id="test" controls="controls" autoplay>
<source src="https://SCRIPT" type="audio/ogg; codecs=opus"/>
</audio>

<script>
var obj = document.getElementById('test');

obj.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
    console.log("Can play event");
});

obj.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() {
    console.log("can play through event");
});

obj.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
    console.log("Loaded data event");
    console.log(obj.readyState);
});
</script>
```

I tried "pinging" it with `.play()` but that was unsuccessful.

When joining a stream already at least a minute in progress (server can immediately feed lots of data), the audio starts to play essentially instantaneously. The problem is when the stream is new (i.e. just being created) and there is not enough data to trigger the seemingly arbitrary play point, because the application is supposed to be low overhead.

This level of latency is unacceptable, and, frankly, it's really confusing. Why would you delay streams with lower overhead longer than you would with a more demanding stream? It's opposite what one would consider to be common sense.

I have more complex work arounds in mind, but it would be ideal to make this work with the widely utilized HTML5 audio.

---

### Questions

1. Does anyone know how to force `.play()` even if `readyState` is `0` or before the `canplay` event?
2. Is there a way to modify the initial buffer/latency setting?
3. Any ideas other than putting 30 kB of junk in the file header page?

---

### Updated Info

I logged the `audio.readyState` as frequently as Chrome allowed and discovered it changes from `0` ("HAVE_NOTHING") to `1` (HAVE_METADATA) a few ms before `loadeddata` fires. As I mentioned previously, it changes to `3` ("HAVE_FUTURE_DATA") with `loadeddata`.

Here is a log example from Chrome, the integer at the end is the `readyState`

> 12:49:36.199 StreamTest.php:94 0 (page load)
>
> ... (Prints "0") ...
>
> 12:49:54.497 StreamTest.php:94 0
>
> 12:49:54.503 StreamTest.php:94 1
>
> 12:49:54.505 StreamTest.php:74 Loaded data event
>
> 12:49:54.505 StreamTest.php:75 3
>
> 12:49:54.505 StreamTest.php:66 Can play event

**Update 2**

These are the stream headers:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Sun, 25 Mar 2018 08:54:07 GMT
Server: Apache
Accept-Ranges: none
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: close
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
Content-Type: audio/ogg; codecs=opus
```

---

### Test Page

**Update 3**

I created a test page with a few tests to demonstrate HTML5 Audio Play behavior. See this webpage: http://webtests.online/LiveHTML5Audio.php

Comment: Do you get any errors or warnings about play() as a Promise?

Comment: No. Not on FF or Chrome. Haven't tried others. It just seems to ignore it. I added in the following, and no error messages:  try{
        obj.play();
    }catch(error){
        console.log("Play failed");
        console.log(error);
    }

Comment: Try `preload="auto"` or  "none"

Comment: I tested those in Chrome, and it appears the same behavior. I logged the `audio.readyState` as frequently as Chrome allowed and discovered it changes from `0` ("HAVE_NOTHING") to `1` (HAVE_METADATA) a few ms before `loadeddata` fires. As I mentioned previously, it changes to `3` ("HAVE_FUTURE_DATA") with `loadeddata`. Thanks for stopping by and the tips. I am going to keep trying everything anyone suggests.

Comment: Web Audio APi uses a buffer that should handle problems like that. Here's an [example that uses the `<audio>` tag and audio buffer over XHR](http://webaudioapi.com/samples/audio-tag/)

Comment: Same thing with that approach... I'll study it more. Any ideas?

Comment: @zer00ne That's not relevant to the problem Justin is having.

Comment: @Justin There are a few causes for this... the first is that there *are* some fixed sized buffers still around.  These are effectively bugs, in my opinion.  Can you post your sample audio file though?  Also, post the request/response headers you see in your network panel.  The key here is to first ensure that the Ogg is actually playable before that 32 KB mark, and that the browser doesn't have to guess the type.  One alternative approach that *may* have different results is MSE, but before we resort to that, post more info.  Thanks.

Comment: I added the headers as received by Chrome to the answer as Update 2. I don't have a good way to post a sample. I'll try to make something tomorrow. It's different than a traditional live stream in that the user will always want to start from the beginning, even if they are behind. As far as the file being playable, I'm confident that it is. For example, if the entire file (e.g. a short audio segment) is sent before the 32 kB is hit, the file will play immediately (with readyState of `4`).

Comment: @Brad I created a test page. See the update in the question for the link.

Comment: FYI followers, bounty added.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the delay you can just duplicate audio channels (up to 8) and/or do upscale